# Unprotect worksheets based on username

Tags: vba, macros, microsoft-excel-2016

[image]I have a VBA code that will unlock ALL of the sheets in my workbook, but it will not run automatically when I open the workbook.

Comment: No need to comment to bump. Super User is staffed by normal people. If someone who sees your question has an answer they are free to post it. In the meantime, you could use the formatting tools to improve your question. Right now it's just a jumbled pile of code which makes it very difficult to read and understand. Also, you haven't told us where the code is failing and what messages you receive when it fails. Finally, have you researched the various authentication plugins VBA offers?

Comment: I am very unfamiliar with this side of excel.  I am trying to learn the best I can in the amount of time I have.  I have spent the last two weeks trying to find a solution to this and only stumbled onto this website.  So far everyone has been EXTREMELY helpful!  The only problem with my code is that it will not run automatically when the file is opened.  I posted a picture of my code above.  I appreciate everyone's help on this!!

Comment: Which module is this VBA in? It must be in the `ThisWorkbook` module to execute automatically.

Comment: It has its own module in the Modules folder.

Comment: I moved it to the location that you specified and it worked like a champ!  Thank you!  Can you take a look at my other question about code to automatically reinstate the protection upon closing the workbook?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1221877/reinstate-worksheet-protection-upon-save-and-close

Comment: Can you add your solution as an answer so I can check it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be in the ThisWorkbook module to execute automatically. – Andi Mohr posted this answer and it worked great!

Comment: It is best to ask the commentor to place their comment as the answer if it is. There are points involved, and just copy/pasting someone elses comment as an answer can be seen as quite rude.